# where are those files in app->build come from?

Tags: android

I am new in android, and I wonder where those files in app->build come from, I mean how they were built. And where can I go and find the knowledge about these things? [The link below is the image I captured from android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG14M.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `build` folder holds your build files. Cleaning your project also removes the files in this folder. It holds intermediary(e.g. classes, generated files, etc.) and result files (e.g. apk).

https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

Comment: Why we need intermediary? I mean ,for example, I find the AndroidManifest.xml in intermediates->manifests->full->debug, it is the same as the source file in my module

Comment: The `Manifest.xml` from your project (including manifests from submodules - if you have any) are merged with the settings in your `build.gradle` from the `android {}` object (e.g. package name, SDK version, etc.). That's why the toolset generates an intermediary one. You can define these settings solely in `Manifest.xml`, but many can also just solely be defined in `build.gradle` and built by gradle into the intermediary `manifest.xml` that is used to build your app.